# Bootstrap 3 Ruby app not mobile responsive

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku

According to my research, Bootstrap 3 is supposed to be mobile-reponsive by default. However, when I try to visit my Rails 4 app (deployed on Heroku) on my iPhone 5S, it looks exactly the same as the desktop layout (with smaller text).

App: http://wheels2015.herokuapp.com

Github repo: https://github.com/yamilethmedina/wheels_registration

I would add more specific code, but i'm not sure what portion of the massive `bootstrap.css` file would be relevant to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's difficult to say for sure using just the information in the question you posted, but my guess is you forgot to [set the viewport](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-mobile).

Quote:

> To ensure proper rendering and touch zooming, add the viewport meta tag to your `<head>`.
>
> ```
> <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
> ```

Comment: Is this in `application.html.erb`? I don't see a `<head>` in any of the css files.

Comment: @YamiMedina Yes. On Rails that's typically where you'd put it.

Comment: Thanks, this is really helpful! Some of my grid layouts (like the one on the login page) are a bit off, but the rest of it is great! :)

Answer (score 0):

> You don't use `bootstrap grid system`.

It will ensure correct placement of your elements depending device resolution.

- [bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/)